Does rebasing a branch automatically make changes in package.json?
I encountered an issue after rebasing PR onto a new base branch. Here’s what happened:

After the rebase, I noticed that package.json showed up as modified in PR, even though I never made any changes to it.

I double-checked and confirmed that I never committed or pushed any changes to package.json

Also the changes in package doesn’t seem to match with newly rebased branch.


Have anyone experienced this before? Thank you so much!

show git diff, or show screenshot of commits where we can see changes, anything

No, rebasing doesn’t arbitrarily change text files.

Was there an squash involved somewhere in the branches you are dealing with? In the PR, all the commits that are showing up in there belong to your development? Or it's including commits from other things?

This could happen if the rebase you ran tried to rewrite too many commits. Depending on how many extra commits you included and their contents, you likely have other issues besides just that one file.
